# Is Skynet from first Terminator the same as the one from Terminator 2: Judgment Day?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator, terminator-2-judgment-day

As future has changed in *Terminator*, did it also affect Skynet?

Is Skynet from *Terminator 2: Judgment Day* completely different, or, simply a stronger iteration that is trying to fix the errors previous one made?

Comment: T1: Skynet is created by Cyberdyne from the scratch. 

T2: Dyson creates Skynet by reverse-engineering the first Terminator

Comment: I will compose the answer soon; if not someone can use the info above to do it

Comment: “future has changed in Terminator” — or [_**HAS IT?!?!?!?!?**_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYkBSFKCDog)

Comment: "T1: Skynet is created by Cyberdyne from the scratch" — or [_**IS IT?!?!?!?!?**_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYkBSFKCDog)

Comment: I've voted to close because the question (as written) makes no sense. The Skynet that is mentioned in T2 is the same Skynet *sending back a second Terminator*.

Comment: @Valorum actually no. Different companies developed it and first one lost the war in the future, thus it is sending T-800 to the past.

Comment: @Valorum so it still fails, but leaves a chip and a hand, thus letting the creation of second one.

Comment: @Gravemind - In both cases the terminators were Cyberdyne Models.

Comment: @Valorum how it can be the same if first one was destroyed at the end of T1. Second one is another iteration aware of previous mistakes, thus using T-1000 instead of T-800 to kill JC.

Comment: @Gravemind - The one that was destroyed in T1 was a Cyberdyne model. As was the one seen in T2. It follows that both were designed by the same company (which incidentally is the same organisation that designed Skynet).

Comment: @Valorum I’m not asking about it’s parent company. I’m asking if there are different iterations of Skynet in a time loop.

Comment: @Gravemind - Not in the first two films. That's the whole point. Now if you were asking about film 3....